# Discord.py (Not the rewrite). How to accept multiple inputs for on_message

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am using the the Discord.py library (not the rewrite) for my discord bot. I have a command that corrects the users grammar whenever the user sends a message.

Such as:

```
elif message.content.find("your"):
    await message.channel.send("*you're")
```

This method works as it can detect the word even if it in a sentence. Such as if the user says "your cool", the bot will pick it up and send "you're". I would like for it to detect more than one input though as I do not want a 300 line long if-elif-else ladder.

Such as:

```
elif message.content.find("your", "ur", "yor"):
    await message.channel.send("*you're")
```

Error:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

So I am wondering if there is a way to do this as I have not seen much from the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list like `['ur', 'your', 'yor']`, then you can loop through this list and check if one of them is in the `message.content`. So you can simply use this:

```
[await message.channel.send("*you're") for m in ['ur', 'your', 'yor'] if m in message.content]
```

or you can use

```
word_list = ['ur', 'your', 'yor']
for m in word_list:
    if m in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("*you're")
        return
```

Comment: And where exactly would I put this in my code? I have def on_message: then a long line of if-elif. Would it be:  "elif message.content in word_list:" ? or would it be a client.command?       @Nurqm

Comment: You should add it inside the `on_message` event, just add it somewhere in there.

Comment: For some reason when I type "your" into discord it responds with "you're" 2 times. It does not do this with "yor" and "ur". Evidence: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/769198899680247828/774319616934936636/Screen_Shot_2020-11-06_at_12.09.14_PM.png  (I do not have any other commands that respond to "your")